# ruflin elastica how to use _source to get certain fields

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

how to use _source  to get certain fields in ruflin elastica.
please suggest how to use it.

For Ex:

```
{
"_source": {"user", "message"},
"query" : {
    "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
}
}
```

How can i convert this to ruflin elastica.
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query class provides a `setSource` method to add the list of fields, as an array, you want to retrieve.

Some code I use to make a query by using `ruflin/elastica v3.2` and ElasticSearch 2.4 can be:

```
$search = new Search(new Elastica\Client());    
$query = new Elastica\Query();
$query->setSource(['user', 'message']

$boolQuery = new Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();
$boolQuery->addMust(new Term(['user' => 'kimchy']));

$query->setQuery((new BoolQuery())->addMust(new MatchAll())->addFilter($boolQuery));
$search->setQuery($query);

try {
        $resultSet = $search->search();
} catch (ResponseException $exception) {
    // code
}

$results = $resultSet->getResults();
```